# Центрирование блочных элементов

Tags: html, css

Проблема с центрированием блочных элементов в разделе **HTML** `<main></main>`.

**Реальность**
[image: Реальность]

**Ожидание**
[image: Ожидание]

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

header .headerline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.headerline #logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.maincontainer div {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div .news-title {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div .addnews-block {
  padding: 5px;
}

div .author-name {
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Babeikin\Desktop\Untitled-1.css">
<header>
  <div class="headerline">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="C:\Users\Babeikin\Desktop\logo.png" alt="LOGO НЕ ЗАГРУЖАЕТСЯ" srcset="">
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <div id="newsblock_red">
      <h1>[NEWSBLOCK]</h1>
      <p class="news-title">Новости региона:</p><br>
      <P class="addnews-block">На этой неделе в Могилёве произошло 10 дорожно-транпортных происшествий</P><br>
      <p class="author-name">Автор: Е.В. Бабейкин</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sportblock_green">
      <h1>[SPORTBLOCK]</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="autoblog_blue">
      <h1>[AUTOBLOG]</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="comments_white">
      <h1>[COMMENTS]</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="foootline">
    <div id="company">
    </div>
    <div id="support">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Эм... а какое поведение ожидается? Хоть скриншот приложите что ли...

Comment: Добавил скриншоты в начало вопроса.

Comment: Для блока main задайте стили `display: flex; justify-content: center` - тогда его содержимое расположится по центру.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Я только учусь)

Comment: @baobabich, если какой-либо из ответов решил Вашу проблему - отметьте его в качестве верного решения, нажав на галочку слева от текста ответа.

Comment: Отметил вроде как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для расположения блока по центру контейнера горизонтально можно использовать свойство `margin:auto`.

```css
.to-cen {
  /* выравнивается горизонтально по центру родителя */
  margin: auto;
  
  /* нужно фиксировать размер блочного элемента */
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  
  /* для цветовой дифференциации */
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="to-cen"></div>
```

В случае, если требуется выполнить центрирование содержимого по вертикали, то самое простое решение — применить технологию гибких контейнеров.

```css
body {
  /* включить поддержку FlexBox */
  display: flex;
  
  /* растянуть содержимое страницы как минимум на весь экран */
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
  /* задать выравнивание по вертикали (перпендикулярно оси контейнера) */
  align-items: center;
  /* задать выравнивание по горизонтали (вдоль оси контейнера) */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
```